# Description indented too much inside framed (in Hebrew)

Tags: framed, description, hebrew

I'm writing lecture notes in Hebrew using lyx. I use the `framed` package to have my theorems inside a nice gray box. It all seemed to work fine, until I noticed a strange behavior when I try to put a description list inside.

Here's how it looks like:
[image]

I tried to create a MWE in English for you, but there was no such problem, so apparantly it has something to do with Hebrew. Here's how it looks, in comparison:
[image]

Both use the exact same code in the document preamble:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.8, .8, .8}
\newenvironment{myframe}{
\def\FrameCommand{\colorbox{shadecolor}}%
\MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width }}
{\endMakeFramed}

\newtheorem{newThm}[thm]{\bfseries Theorem}
\renewenvironment{thm}
{\begin{myframe}\begin{newThm}\begin{normalfont}}
{\end{normalfont}\end{newThm}\end{myframe}}
```

So I don't know how to locate the problem. If anyone has any ideas I'd be happy to hear. Also, sorry if this the question is not written properly, I'm new here... Thanks!

**Edit:** Here's a full Latex code of my MWE, generated by Lyx. I'm sorry that it turned out quite long, it's the best I could do!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{David}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}
\setmonofont{Miriam Fixed}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatletter

% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}
\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}

% This is the preamble!
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.8, .8, .8}
\newenvironment{myframe}{
\def\FrameCommand{\colorbox{shadecolor}}%
\MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width }}
{\endMakeFramed}

\newtheorem{newThm}[thm]{\bfseries Theorem}
\renewenvironment{thm}
{\begin{myframe}\begin{newThm}\begin{normalfont}}
   {\end{normalfont}\end{newThm}\end{myframe}}
%This is the end of the preamble!

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\normalsize\(\bullet\)}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}}
\addto\captionshebrew{\renewcommand{\theoremname}{משפט}}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{משפט}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
לורם איפסום:
\begin{enumerate}
\item דולור סיט אמט.
\item דולור סיט אמט.
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
לורם איפסום:
\begin{description}
\item [{דולור.}] סיט אמט.
\item [{דולור.}] סיט אמט.
\end{description}
\end{thm}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! I’m not sure I can duplicate your bug unless you share the full code. Could you post a complete [MWE that we can compile and test?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad news is that I can’t reproduce your bug.  The good news is, I didn’t reproduce your bug.  Without a MWE, I can’t tell you why you’re getting that error, but here’s a MWE that works (in TeX Live 2020 with LuaLaTeX).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.tabular, nil]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor} % For \colorbox
\usepackage{framed} % For \MakeFramed
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{translator} % For \providetranslation, \trnaslate

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX, Renderer=HarfBuzz }

% The Culmus fonts are free for download at
% https://sourceforge.net/projects/culmus/
\defaultfontfeatures[DavidCLM]{
   UprightFont = *-Medium,
   ItalicFont = *-MediumItalic,
   BoldFont = *-Bold,
   BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
   Extension = .otf }

\defaultfontfeatures[MiriamCLM]{
  UprightFont = *-Book,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  Extension = .ttf }

\babelprovide[import]{english}
\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0, Language=Default]{NewComputerModernBook}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Language=Default]{NewComputerModernSansBook}
\babelfont{tt}
          [Language=Default]{NewComputerModernMonoBook}

\babelprovide[import, main]{hebrew}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}
          [Language=Default]{DavidCLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}
          [Language=Default]{MiriamCLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{tt}
          [Language=Default]{MiriamMonoCLM}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}
\setmathrm{NewComputerModernBook}
\setmathsf{NewComputerModernSansBook}
\setmathtt{NewComputerModernMonoBook}

\providetranslation[to=Hebrew]{Theorem}{משפט}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.8, .8, .8}
\newenvironment{myframe}{
\def\FrameCommand{\colorbox{shadecolor}}%
\MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width }}
{\endMakeFramed}

\newcounter{thm}
\newtheorem{newThm}[thm]{\bfseries \translate{Theorem}}
\newenvironment{thm}
{\begin{myframe}\begin{newThm}\begin{normalfont}}
{\end{normalfont}\end{newThm}\end{myframe}}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}{לורם איפסום}
\begin{description}
\item[לורם]
איפסום

\item[דולור]
טיט אמט
\end{description}
\end{thm}

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\begin{thm}{Lorem Ipsum}
\begin{description}
\item[Lorem]
Ipsum

\item[Dolor]
Sit amet
\end{description}
\end{thm}
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

[image: David CLM / New Computer Modern sample]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately when I tried copying the relevant part to my preamble it just gave me a bunch of errors which I could not fix. Maybe it has something to do with you using LuaLaTeX while I use Xetex.

Comment: I figured out how to let Lyx export a latex file for me (in Xetex). It is quite long and probably not a minimal Latex code, but it is what I could do... I'll copy the code to my edited question. Again, sorry that I'm now savvy enough to give you the ideal setup for helping me.

Comment: @35T41 Yes, that would be the reason. I can post a version that works in XeTeX, but it won’t have every feature LuaTeX supports.

Comment: I edited my question, now it contains a complete latex code. I guess this is a downside of working with Lyx instead of directly with Latex. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @35T41 Okay. `framed` seems to have this bug when compiling with XeLaTeX, but not LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Strange. Can anything be done to overcome this issue? Maybe some ad-hoc trick?

Comment: Well, adding `\normalcolor` along with `\bfseries` in the theorem formatting and `layout=sectioning.tabular.lists` to the Babel options seems to mitigate, but not eliminate, the problem in XeTeX. If you can’t switch to LuaLaTeX, maybe you can replace the description lists.

Comment: OK, I'll try that. Thanks again!

Comment: @35T41 Also, there seems to be a bug with `fontspec` not being able to find `NewComputerModernBook.fontspec`, etc., in XeTeX, so my example font command won’t work, and you’d need to load `NewCM10-Book`, `NewCMSans10-Book`, etc. This is incidental to the main issue.